# How to set collation for a specific Column in a Sequelize model?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

How to set collation for a specific Column in a Sequelize model?

I tried this:

```
name: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  collate: 'utf8_general_ci'
},
```

Apparently it doesn't work. Any other ideia?

Comment: do you want to map the column named "name", in this case?

Comment: yes, or for any other.

Comment: sorry @Tiago Bértolo I thought your problem was in the construction of the model. Had not read the word "collate"

Comment: No problem mate. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Try this `Sequelize.STRING + ' CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci'` in your type

Comment: Didn't work! Nice attempt though! :D

Comment: hum... this works for me

Comment: What your sequelize version? Your different charset is only for this column or all database?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several things you can do to support:

**Table level:**

```
sequlize.define('table', {

}, {
    charset: 'utf8',
    collate: 'utf8_general_ci'
})
```

**Column level:**

```
sequelize.define('table', {
    column: Sequelize.STRING + ' CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci'
})
```

**Database level:**

```
let sequelize = new Sequelize('database', {
    dialectOptions: {
        charset: 'utf8',
        collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok... Let's try, at some point, we can get it right. Set the define in sequelize... whith the column level sample. Outside your model